# How to navigate with popViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development and I'm using parse.com  as my backend.
I want to navigate from **[View Controller 2]** to **[view Controller 3]**
but is not working right.
Here is the code
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6zZg.jpg

```
NSString *username = [self.usernameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


NSString *email = [self.emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 || [email length] == 0){

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Make sure you enter a username, password , and email address!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show]; // This help to show your message successfully!
}
else {
    PFUser *newUser  = [PFUser user]; // This is a method to create new users

    newUser.username = username;

    newUser.password = password;

    newUser.email    = email;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alertView show];

        }
        else {


  [self.navigationController popToViewController:_profilePhotoViewController animated:YES];


        }

    }];
}

}
```

Comment: Do you want to push or pop your view controller ?

Comment: What is not working? are you presenting your view modally?

Comment: i want to use popViewController @HaniIbrahim please check out the storyboard chart link http://i.stack.imgur.com/t6zZg.jpg

Comment: @CaptJak the code [self.navigationController popToViewController:_profilePhotoViewController animated:YES];
 is not opening the view controller i want to access. please view this link to see the storyboard transition http://i.stack.imgur.com/t6zZg.jpg

Comment: `popToRootViewController` will remove all View controller on the stack which are on top of the rootView, which in your picture, looks like it would be the welcome page. In other words, it will not present any VC, it will remove them.Where are yo trying to go? From Welcome to VC1? Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Thanks @CaptJak you are right. i am trying to go to the Home"VC3" and yes i am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the image you posted, VC3 is not displayed nor pushed to the controller before displaying VC2

This method `popToViewController:animated:` require that the controller is displayed before and in the controller stack in order to pop the stack back to it

You can achieve what you want by pop to root and then push your view

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_profilePhotoViewController animated:YES];
```

Besure that `_profilePhotoViewController` is allocated before pushing it

.

.

---

**UPDATE**

In your storyboard set an identifier to your VC3 to be for example "VC3Identifier"

You can do this as you can see in the below image

1. Choose your controller
2. Show the utilities
3. show the identity inspector
4. Put 'VC3Identifier' in StoryBoard ID field

[image]

Then You will need to allocate a new instance of this controller and add it to the navigation controller

```
YourController *vc3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3Identifier"];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[vc3] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to get to the View Controller 3 (Home) but it is taking me to the (welcome page). what should i do?

Comment: Try this code `self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[_profilePhotoViewController];` but this will have no animation

Comment: i tried it and got this:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]' *** First throw call stack:

Comment: what is the best way to do that? please

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, I am not totally sure how your code works and what will trigger the change of View, but in your code where you call this:

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:_profilePhotoViewController animated:YES];
```

Is what you need to handle (assuming profilePhotoViewController is VC3).

Go to your Storyboard and ctrl+click+drag from the presenting view (the VC that you are starting from) and end up at VC 3. VC 3 should light up blue. Let go and you will see a drop down menu. Select "Push". This will create a segue for you to transition. Next you need to give it an identifier, so click on the segue that was just made and go to the Attributes Inspector and in the "Identifier" field type in "ProfilePictureSegue" and then press enter (or return).

Then go to the file that contains the code you posted and replace

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:_profilePhotoViewController animated:YES];
```

With:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ProfilePictureSegue"];
```

And bob is your uncle. Run it.

**EDIT**
I looked at your picture again and it looks like your VC3 is in the wrong place. Create a segue from VC2 to VC 3, not from the Navigation Controller to VC3. Call the segue, as I explained above, in the VC2 .m file, and it will transition between.

If you need more [explanations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardSegue.html).

Comment: Thanks but i got this...Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<RegisterViewController: 0x98a6490>) has no segue with identifier 'ProfilePictureSeque''... The VC3 is connected to the Navigation Controller

Comment: is there any way i can navigate to VC3 because that is where am trying to go. I cannot create a segue from VC2 to VC3 because VC2 has a signup button that sends data to parse to validate signup or login access. if the data if correct then it is to link to Profile Picture view controller.

Comment: Regarding the error, the correct word is segue, NOT seque. It is a "G". Otherwise, you either didn't set the identifier or the identifier in code doesn't match the identifier in the segue. Where are you trying to navigate to VC 3 from? When you plan a trip, you don't tell the airline "I want to go to France". You say "I want to go from Spain to France". What is the source point?